# How to start different activity for each positive button on the dialog shown from ListView item click event

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-dialog

I have a `ListView` with a custom adapter using `customlistadapter`. If the item or row is clicked it will show an `AlertDialog` with `negative` and `positive` buttons. Now I want for every `positive` button in the `AlertDialog` to start a different Activity.

Ex : If I click positive button in the dialog from list/row number one, it will be show Activity1 and if I click positive button in the dialog in list/row number two, it will show Activity2.

This is my `MenuList.java` :

```
public class MenuList extends ActionBarActivity{

ListView list;
String[] itemname ={
        "RM. Kemang raya",
        "Granny's Nest",
        "RM. Dua Saudara",
        "Solaria Giant",
        "Rumah Kayu",
        "RM. Mbok Wito 2",
};

String[] itemdescription ={
        "[Umum]\nJl.Endro Suratmin Sukarame, Bandar Lampung.\nTelp.0721723732",
        "[Cafe]\nJl.P.Antasari Gg.P.Sebuku Sukarame, Bandar Lampung.\nTelp.0821 8619 8999",
        "[Masakan Padang]\nJl.P.Tirtayasa Sukabumi, Bandar Lampung.\nTelp.0721745627",
        "[Umum/Cafe]\nJl.P.Antasari Sukarame, Bandar Lampung.\nTelp.0721 773066",
        "[Umum]\nJl.Arief Rahman Hakim No. 45, Bandar Lampung.\nTelp.0721 700666",
        "[Umum]\nJl.Arief Rahman Hakim Blok A No.16, Bandar Lampung.\nTelp.0721 701298",
};

Integer[] imgid={
        R.drawable.ic_listrestro,
        R.drawable.ic_listrestro,
        R.drawable.ic_listrestro,
        R.drawable.ic_listrestro,
        R.drawable.ic_listrestro,
        R.drawable.ic_listrestro,
};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_restoran);

    // enable up/back button
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MenuRestoran.this, MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, itemdescription, imgid);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Slecteditem= itemname[+position];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //alert dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MenuRestoran.this);
            adb.setTitle(itemname[+position]);
            adb.setMessage("Lihat Lokasi di Map?");
            adb.setIcon(imgid[+position]);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Lihat", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MenuRestoran.this, MapsRMKemang.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            adb.setNegativeButton("Batal", null);
            adb.show();

        }
    });
}
```

This is my `CustomListAdapter.java`:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final String[] itemdescription;
private final Integer[] imgid;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, String[] itemdescription, Integer[] imgid) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_view, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
    this.itemdescription = itemdescription;
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, null, true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView Descriptiontxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    Descriptiontxt.setText(itemdescription[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    return rowView;

};
```

have you guys can tell me to do this? Thanks

Comment: Let me know if the simple solution I posted works!  I think it should work but I have not tested it.

Comment: @DanielNugent I think it simple code and gonna be work, just wait my android studio to rebuild project :)

Comment: @DanielNugent Thank you Sir, your code work great, it's just simple code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have most of the code, you just need to add a check for the `position` that was clicked on that initiated the `AlertDialog`.

You'll have to add a `final int pos` so that it can be accessed in the inner `onClickListener()` in `setPositiveButton()`:

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Slecteditem= itemname[+position];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            final int pos = position; //added

            //alert dialog
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MenuRestoran.this);
            adb.setTitle(itemname[+position]);
            adb.setMessage("Lihat Lokasi di Map?");
            adb.setIcon(imgid[+position]);
            adb.setPositiveButton("Lihat", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    //New Code below:
                    if (pos == 0) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MenuRestoran.this, Activity1.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else  if (pos == 1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MenuRestoran.this, Activity2.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    //end new code.....
                }
            });
            adb.setNegativeButton("Batal", null);
            adb.show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter,

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private ClickCallback clickCallback;

    public void setClickCallback(ClickCallback clickCallback) {
        this.clickCallback = clickCallback;
    }
```

in `getView`

```
rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListner() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (clickCallback == null) {
            return;
        }
        clickCallback.invoke(position);
    }
};);
```

You may attach listener on positive and negative buttons.

Here `clickCallback` is your custom class which you need to implement to handle callbacks.

```
public interface ClickCallback {
    public void invoke(int position);
}
```

In your activity,

```
private class PositiveCallback implements ClickCallback {
    public void invoke(int position) {
        // call your activities
    }
}

 CustomListAdapter adapter=new CustomListAdapter(this, itemname, itemdescription, imgid);
 adapter.setClickCallback(new PositiveCallback());
```

Comment: Hi @Froyo thanks for your answer, can you implement the code in my `MenuList.java` and my `CustomListAdapter.java` ? I realy hope it. Thanks in advance